# Natural proof steps for predicate

Tags: predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am trying to prove the following predicate by using natural deduction rules but I do not see the way to do it:

∀ x(P(x) ∨ Q(x)) ⊢ ~∀x(~P(x) ∧ ~Q(x))

Is this predicate derivable? if yes please provide the natural deduction steps or a hint to solve it.

Solution using @Mauro ALLEGRANZA's hint:

[image: Solution steps]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*

The conclusion is negated; thus, the first idea is to assume : $∀x(\lnot P(x) ∧ \lnot Q(x))$ and derive a contradicition, concluding with $\lnot$-intro.

Thus, the first steps must be :

1) $∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x))$ --- premise

2) $∀x(\lnot P(x) ∧ \lnot Q(x))$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\lnot P(x) ∧ \lnot Q(x)$ --- from 2) by $∀$-elim

4) $\lnot P(x)$ --- from 3) by $∧$-elim

5) $\lnot Q(x)$ --- from 3) by $∧$-elim

6) $P(x) ∨ Q(x)$ --- from 1) by $∀$-elim.

Now the derivation is straightforward, using $∨$-elim.